# Display error messages returned from API into Flutter UI

Tags: flutter, dart, laravel-api

Display error messages returned from API into Flutter UI.

I am new to Flutter. My Laravel API returns the following response, I am successfully receiving the response but I am unable to find a way to display these messages in UI, I am using Flushbar to display messages. Please help.

```
{
 "data":{
  "errors": {
    "email": [
        "The email has already been taken."
    ],
    "password": [
        "The password must be at least 6 characters.",
        "The password confirmation does not match."
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from showing the message exactly? It is not clear what the problem is. are you able to properly receive the error from the api call? do you have a class to deserialize to json into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var res = {
  "data":{
    "errors": {
      "email": [
        "The email has already been taken."
      ],
      "password": [
        "The password must be at least 6 characters.",
        "The password confirmation does not match."
      ]
    }
  }
};

res["data"]["errors"].forEach((key, messages) { 
  if ("email" == key) {
    // show email errors like this
    for (var message in messages) {
      // Use your Flushbar here to show the error message
    }
  } else if ("password" == key) {
    // show password erros like this 
    for (var message in messages) {
      // Use your Flushbar here to show the error message
    }
  }
});
```

**Edit**
To be shorter, you can combine your messages as one like this

```
String combinedMessage = "";

res["data"]["errors"].forEach((key, messages) {      
  for (var message in messages) combinedMessage = combinedMessage + "- $message\n";
  // Use your Flushbar here to show combinedMessage variable
});
```

Comment: But it is displaying only the last message in Flushbar even though it contains all 3 error messages ie. "The password confirmation does not match."

Comment: See the edit section